# How to bind to a resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm struggling with some binding in what is for me, a complicated set up. To recreate the situation, I've created a new WPF project which has removed everything other than this problem.

My MainWindow has it's datacontext set in the code behind (this.DataContext = this;). Within the MainWindow, there is a single user control. My research shows that the `UserControl` automatically inherits the `DataContext` from its parent. So, in order to make UserControl have it's own DataContext, I can do this int he code behind with code similar to `MyUserControlsCanvas.DataContext = this;`. This works as desired

The problem is, my UserControl has a reference to a class and that is inherited via the RealtiveSource TemplatedParent and as such, I can't bind. Now, I appreciate this part probably makes no sense so let me show the full code (sorry, there is quite a bit).

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:myControl="clr-namespace:BindingTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <myControl:MyControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    ...
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this; // this is required although not shown why in this example
        }
    }
```

MyControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingTest.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:myControl="clr-namespace:BindingTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Canvas.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate x:Key="ResizeDecoratorTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="LightSkyBlue" Opacity=".1"></SolidColorBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <myControl:MoveMe Width="3" Test="{Binding HOW_DO_I_BIND_HERE}" Cursor="SizeWE" Margin="-2 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightGreen"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Canvas.Resources>
            <ContentControl Width="130"
                    MinWidth="50"
                    x:Name ="MyCanvas"
                    MinHeight="50"
                    Canvas.Top="0"
                    Canvas.Left="1"
                    Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MyControl.xaml.cs

```
    ...
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyCanvas.DataContext = this;
            this.ValueOfLeftBorder = 5;
        }

        //Dependancy properties, properties and methods

        public double ValueOfLeftBorder { get; set; }
        public double ValueOfRightBorder { get; set; }
    }
```

MoveMe.cs

```
    ...
    public class MoveMe : Thumb
    {
        public double Test
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(TestProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           "Test",
           typeof(double),
           typeof(MainWindow));    

        public MoveMe()
        {
            base.DragDelta += this.ResizeThumb_DragDelta;
        }

        private void ResizeThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            //Logic
            MessageBox.Show("I Moved");
        }
    }
```

Within MyControl.xaml I have the following code

```
<myControl:MoveMe Width="3" Test="{Binding HOW_DO_I_BIND_HERE}" Cursor="SizeWE" Margin="-2 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightGreen"/>
```

I am trying to bind to Test.

My main goal here is just to find Y Positions of this moveable item. I am creating a timeline where I want to be able to select the start and end points. Here is a screen shot of what it currently looks like. Please note, this works fine other than, I need to know the Y Position of the start (light green vertical line) and (dark green vertical line).

[image]

Comment: didn't you mean to register Test with owner MoveMe instead of MainWindow?

Comment: this line of code : 
  <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">

is redundant it will inherit it's Parent's DataContext any ways.

Comment: Test="{Binding HOW_DO_I_BIND_HERE}" , What is it you wan't to bind to ?

your Window ?

Comment: @eranotzap, no, I want to know the value of the Y Position. I updated my question to show exactly what I'm after

Comment: @DaveRook and where is that Y position , which element in your screen holds it ? (either as a DP or a property of it's DataContext ) 
?

FYI knowing that you wanted Y position as apposed to Binding to A bunny rabbit does not changed my question , what element is your Visual Tree are you trying to bind to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your purpose but if you have a MoveMe xaml like:

```
<UserControl...>
    <Thumb x:Name="root" DragDelta="ResizeThumb_DragDelta">
        <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
    </Thumb>
</UserControl>
```

and code behind of

```
    public double Test
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(TestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Test",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(MoveMe));

    private void ResizeThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Margin = new Thickness(Margin.Left + e.HorizontalChange,0,0,0);
        Test = Margin.Left;
        //or resize ...
    }
```

and MyControl xaml like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="LightSkyBlue" Opacity=".1"></SolidColorBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <myControl:MoveMe Width="30" Cursor="SizeWE" 
Test="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=myControl:MyControl}, Path=ValueOfLeftBorder, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
Margin="-2 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="2" 
BorderBrush="LightGreen"/>
</Grid>
```

your `ValueOfLeftBorder` is kept updated by dragging the `MoveMe`

Comment: OK, I've copied and pasted the code, all works excellent. I'm going to now update the real project with this, so please don't think I'm not responding or I've forgotten if there is a delay! :)

Comment: Take your time dave;)

Comment: Thank you, this simplified my approach, my code *and* it works!